# react native fs readDir result is empty in render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get files in a directory and trying to show them all in the **render**. But it seems the `this.setState` set the returned files in state array, but when I try to console it in **render** function it throws **empty[]** at first render

```
  componentDidMount(){
      RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath) // On Android, use "RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath" (MainBundlePath is not defined)
            .then((result) => {
              this.setState({filesList: result});
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err.message, err.code);
            });
    }
```

**render function**

```
 render() {
      const { filesList } = this.state;
        console.warn(filesList);
        return(

          <ImageViewer imageUrls={filesList}
          renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
          />
        )
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it throws empty[] at first'?

Comment: on console.warn I am getting the empty result like `[]`

Comment: This is just a thought but setState sometimes doesn't get updated immediately so when you console log filesList, you'd be logging the old state which is, in fact, an empty array. Try adding an if statement inside your render method and see if it correctly logs your state

Comment: adding if statement also not working, as the state is already rendered empty, it says nothing was returned from render

Comment: Try passing a callback function in `this.setState({ filesList: result })` and see if it's actually inserting anything in it. Quick ex: `this.setState({ filesList: result }, _ => console.log(this.state.filesList))`

Comment: this `this.setState({ filesList: result }, _ => console.warn(this.state.filesList))` callback is working, the problem is render part, when I try to console it in render it throws empty state